# Trailing slashes causing error code 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this `htaccess` script

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

So i can get access a page like `example.com/test` but when i try to go to `example.com/test/` it throws a 500 error. Can someone tell me what needs to change for it to work? Probably a stupid error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change pattern from `^(.+)$` to one that will handle trailing slash separately: `^(.*[^/])/?$`

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

This will work for both `/test` and `/test/` -- both will be rewritten to `/test.php`.

If you want different behaviour, to have `/test` working but have "404 Not Found" error for `/test/` (instead of stupid "500 Server-side" error) you can use this:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The rule above will check if target file exists BEFORE making rewrite .. so if `/test.php` does not exist, no rewrite will occur.