# WAMP - Trailing Slash (/) Gives Error 500 "Internal Server Error" - .htaccess Error?

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

I use WAMP on my computer and when coding my website I decided to remove the .html extension in hopes of improving aesthetics.

This works fine, so, in my case, temp.jakegriffin.co.uk/index.html became /index which is what I wanted. Unfortunately, if there is a trailing / after index, I get:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete     your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

When I attempt to fix this in the .htaccess file, I either get the error 403 were I'm forbidden or the error 404 were the page does not exist.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

That is the code in my .htaccess file for the removal of the extension. If someone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Comment: what does apache error log says..?

Answer (score 0):

This this mod_rewrite rule:

```
 * http://planetozh.com/blog/2004/05/apache-and-the-trailing-slash-problem/

    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteBase    /
    RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -d
    RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])$ $1/
```

Comment: This didn't work either. It just leads to the 404 error when there isn't a trailing slash. However, it does work when there isn't a trailing slash.

Comment: OK -  Please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245542/trailing-slashes-causing-error-code-500

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)[\/*]$ $1.html [L,NC]
```

now you can add a bunch of forward slashes (/) after `index` ;)

Comment: Nah, that didn't work. It just leads to the 404 error when there isn't a trailing slash. However, it does work when there isn't a trailing slash.